# 'module' object has no attribute 'basicConfig'

Tags: python

I have the following code, copied from the Python manual:

```
import logging
LOG_FILENAME = 'example.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
```

When I try to run the script (via `python.exe script.py`) I get an error of `'module' object has no attribute 'basicConfig'`.

However when I copy and paste the code in interactive mode (via python.exe then copy and pasting the actual code) I get no error. The code runs fine.

I have python 2.6.6.

Thank you!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You've got another module called `logging` on the [Python path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path); probably a `logging.py` file in the same directory. Try checking with `print(logging.__file__)`.

Comment: More specifically, a lot of people use a file called X.py for testing module X :)

Comment: @drtf Those using emacs dired-omit-mode are at a particular disadvantage since they don't even see logging.pyc lurking ;)

Comment: I am trying this solution out, but my print out gives me this: `/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py` -- should I check elsewhere?

Comment: @Alex 12 years late, same here :p

Answer (score 16):

You Need to Change your script name into something else rather than logging.py I guess. 
(You are using that name for this script aren't you?

Comment: this one helped me. ty

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same attribute error while running and when checked with current working folder there are 2 filenames with logging. Delete those filenames or move to recycle bin or if imp move to different folder or change names for those logging files and run your program. It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mere side-note for those coding Python in a Google Cloud Function who do not use the Python logging module but `import google.cloud.logging` and who still get the same error.

It is obvious for the reader, but it took me some time to understand this, therefore sharing this.

I thought that the `import google.cloud.logging` would be a kind of wrapper of the Python built-in `logging` module so that it would need the same:

```py
    # Config the logger
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s"
    )
```

But no, the default `Client()` without parameters is enough and text output is either `log_struct` or `log_text`, no log level parameter like `INFO` needed.

**In Google Cloud Function edit mode** (not for a local Python script!)

"requirements.txt":

```
google-cloud-logging==3.0.0
```

"main.py":

```py
    logging_client = gcloud_logger.Client()
    # The name of the log to write to
    log_name = environ['LOG_NAME']
    # Selects the log to write to
    logger = logging_client.logger(log_name)
```

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#log-entries