# Beautiful Soup causing errors when I try to run code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm starting a webscraping project using python. I've followed instructions and installed bs4 to my site-packages directory.

- I'm on Windows 10
- I'm using Atom as my text editor
- The command I used
  was 'pip install bs4' in the directory for site packages

from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mir Cool\Desktop\AutomateBoring\webScraper.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "C:\Users\Mir Cool\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "C:\Users\Mir Cool\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (
  File "C:\Users\Mir Cool\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 19, in <module>
    from bs4.dammit import EntitySubstitution
  File "C:\Users\Mir Cool\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 15, in <module>
    import logging
  File "C:\Users\Mir Cool\Desktop\AutomateBoring\logging.py", line 3, in <module>
    logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG, format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'basicConfig'
```

Comment: A similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482587/module-object-has-no-attribute-basicconfig)

Comment: @YeLinAung Thank you!! I was editing my question but you already did that for me. But thanks for the solution!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['module' object has no attribute 'basicConfig'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482587/module-object-has-no-attribute-basicconfig)