# Python - Various import errors

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the following code copied from "Automate the boring stuffs with python" and it give an error about module import.
 The block code is:

```
import requests

res = requests.get("https://automatetheboringstuff.com/files/rj.txt")
res.raise_for_status()
playFile = open("RomeoAndJuliet.txt", "wb")
for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
    playFile.write(chunk)
playFile.close()
```

And the I error got:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/PYTHON_CODE/webScraping/usingRequests.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PYTHON_CODE\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PYTHON_CODE\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PYTHON_CODE\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 3, in <module>
    import logging
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PYTHON_CODE\logging.py", line 3, in <module>
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=' %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'basicConfig'
```

Please someone help me out by solving this.

Comment: It seems like you have a file called `logging.py` inside of the folder of the script you're trying to launch, and because `urllib` tried to import `logging` (the one in the standard library) it fails. Try to rename the file `logging.py` to something else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['module' object has no attribute 'basicConfig'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482587/module-object-has-no-attribute-basicconfig)